# drupal 7 taxonomy i18n is not working when editing multilingual content.I'm stock to default language

Tags: drupal-7, internationalization, content-type, drupal-taxonomy, pathauto

I create a taxonomy called colors.
Each of my term are translatable, in french and english.

I create a content type called product where I can associate a taxonomy color. Note that my product content type is multilingual aswell

My admin default language is french.

When I create a product,the color taxonomy is only showing in french which is my admin default language. In my mind, it's supose to be displayed within the language set in the node.
It's a problem right now because, english node is associated to french taxonomy.

Anybody know how can I resolve this issue.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your taxonomy was set up.

There are three different modes, beside from no-multilingual:

- Localize. Terms are common for all languages, but their name and description may be localized.
- Translate. Different terms will be allowed for each language and they can be translated.
- Fixed Language. Terms will have a global language and they will only show up for pages in that language.

I guess colors are common for all languages, so I would recommend using the first option.
You can then translate the colors via config > translate interface.

When you chose the "localize" option you don't have duplicate colors showing up on node forms.

### Update

If the terms are common for all languages but you want to add more fields to the terms, you could use *localize* and in addition use the [entity translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module.

Entity translation allows you to translate the different fields for each term.

There are two drawbacks though:

- On top of the entity translation you have to translate the terms via `translate interface` or else the terms will not be translated on the node-edit-forms.
- You have to alter the aliases for the Terms yourself via `/admin/config/search/path` so the terms have different path aliases for different languages

This is of course not a good solution for user-generated terms but works if the terms are moderated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm using the second method (Translate). My concern by using the Localize is that I not only have the name and description to translate, I have more fields. Other things, I want to be able to specify the url alias for each languages and localize do not permit that.

Comment: Internationalization in drupal is a pain in the... I had a similar problem once. I updated my answer with the only working solution I've got.